# diffrence between the DNS setting in etc/resolv conf and etc/network/interfaces

Tags: dns, settings

I want to know the difference between DNS settings in `/etc/resolv.conf` and `/etc/network interfaces`. For example when I share internet connection from other computer(XP), I used to add  the name server (DNS address of my ISP)  in `/etc/resolv.conf` and I could successfully share the internet. But I want to know what is the relevance of setting the DNS address in the `/etc/network/interfaces` along with IP and gateway address?

Where does my computer look up for resolving IP address of some website when browsing? Is it `resolv.conf` or network `interfaces`?

Answer (score 7):

Newer Ubuntu systems use a service called `resolvconf` that runs a local DNS resolver on the machine, and automatically manages the `/etc/resolv.conf` file (in fact, as a symlink to somewhere in the `/run` filesystem) and you should **not** edit the `/etc/resolv.conf` file by hand.

In the *server* version, `resolvconf` takes the actual server addresses either via DHCP or from `/etc/network/interfaces` file where they are specified as a list of `dns-nameservers` e.g.

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.1.102
netmask 255.255.255.0
network 192.168.1.0
broadcast 192.168.1.255
gateway 192.168.1.1
dns-nameservers 192.168.1.1 8.8.4.4
```

For the *desktop* versions (i.e. those using the network-manager service and associated GUI applet) the actual servers come either via DHCP or may be specified in the <kbd>IPv4 Settings</kbd> tab after changing the `Method:` from `Automatic (DHCP)` to either `Automatic (DHCP) addresses only` or `Manual` and adding the required IP addresses in the boxes provided.

Comment: But I want to know where the system look up first for resolving name to ip address